# I am getting redirected to main page after page refresh even if the user is authenticated in private route react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-authentication, react-router

I am working on a private route component that should block un authenticated users and redirect them back to home page, it works fine until I refresh, when I refresh the page the page the current user var get null for one second then it gets the value thus triggering the redirect to main, the problem is even time a user refresh page hi will be refreshed to main and he will have to sign up again.. even though he is signed in

```js
// Auth context
 const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<null | any>(null);
  const [currentClient, setCurrentClient] = useState<null | any>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const context = useContext(exercisesContext);
  const _miscContext = useContext(miscContext);

  console.log(_miscContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true);
    //  with unsubscribe logic !!
    //const unsubscribe =
    onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user: any) => {
      console.log(user, 'test................................');
      // if (!user?.email_verified) {
      //  _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'Please verify your email');
      //  return;
      // }
      setCurrentUser(user);
      setLoading(false);
    });
    //return unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  const Signin = (email: string, password: string) => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        const { user } = userCredential;
        console.log(userCredential.user.emailVerified, 'pppppppp');
        if (!user.emailVerified) {
          _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'Please verify your email');
          return;
        }
        // Signed in
        //const user = userCredential.user;
        //if (user) {
        history.push('/createtraining');
        // }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        console.log(errorCode);
      });
  };

  const Signup = async (email: string, password: string, userType: string) => {
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        //email_verified;

        setDoc(doc(db, 'Data', userCredential.user.uid), {
          createdAt: Timestamp.now(),
        });

        sendEmailVerification(userCredential.user);
        _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'Please check your email');
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        //const errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        if (errorCode === 'auth/weak-password') {
          _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'Password must be at least 6 charechters.');
          history.push('/');
        }
        if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
          _miscContext.SetSnackBarMsg(true, 'Email already exists.');
          history.push('/');
        }
      });
    _miscContext.SetModal(true, '', 'unit');
  };






  return (
    <authContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser,
        currentClient,
        loading,
        Signin,
        Signup,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
};

// Privite route component 
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { authContext } from '../context/auth/AuthState';

interface Props {
  component: any;
  exact: any;
  path: any;
}

export const PrivateRoute: React.FC<Props> = ({ component: Componenet, ...rest }) => {
  const _authContext = useContext(authContext);
  const { currentUser, loading } = _authContext;
  console.log(currentUser);

  return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (!currentUser && !loading ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Componenet />)} />;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that both your initial `currentUser` and `loading` state are falsey.

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<null | any>(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

This means when the app is initially loading/mounting, if the user is attempting to access a protected route they are redirected ***before*** the firsbase auth check has had a chance to complete.

```
export const PrivateRoute: React.FC<Props> = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const _authContext = useContext(authContext);
  const { currentUser, loading } = _authContext;
  console.log(currentUser);

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => (!currentUser && !loading
        ? <Redirect to='/' />
        : <Component />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

## Solution

One possible solution is to start with an initially loading state of true or an indeterminant `currentUser` value that doesn't equal your verified unauthenticated state, and to use an explicit check for either before committing to redirecting or rendering the protected component.

Example:

```
const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState<null | any>();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);
```

...

```
export const PrivateRoute: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
  const _authContext = useContext(authContext);
  const { currentUser, loading } = _authContext;
  console.log(currentUser);

  if (currentUser === undefined || loading) {
    return null; // or loading spinner, etc...
  }

  return currentUser
    ? <Route {...props} />
    : <Redirect to='/' />;
};
```

Comment: life saver.... I set the loading to be true.. works like charm

Comment: I was trying to solve an issue, the component still load for a sec and then the reedit happens how to solve this i mean apparently the component loads for no apparent reason instead of an instant redirect

Comment: shouldn't this logic prevent any renders for the targeted component ?

Comment: @k90-T I think I've seen similar behaviors when using the app is possibly holding on to previous state (*like if you've persisted to localStorage*) and the is reloading it may show old UI/state until everything is refreshed/refetched.

Comment: so this could be normal then. it don't show any data just app bar and stuff but the issue it is just rendering the component for no reason i called a console.log on a useEffect inside the private component and it is getting rendered

Comment: why would the compoent render if it is protected by the logic  return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (!currentUser && !loading ? <Redirect to='/' /> : <Componenet {...props} />)} />

Comment: @k90-T Are you using an early conditional return that is neither the redirect nor routed component?